# how to select last element in the page?

Tags: css, css-selectors

is there any way to select last appear of a specific element with css?

this is an example: [**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/mohsen4887/Ug3PE/)

i tried `last-child` but this is not what i want. i used this class:

**HTML:**

```
<ul>
    <li><span>test</span></li>
    <li>
        <span>test</span>
        <span>test</span>
    </li>
</ul>
<div>
    <span>test</span>
    <span>test</span>
</div>
<p>
    <span>test</span>
    <span>red</span>
</p>
```

**CSS:**

```
span:last-child{
    color:red;
    font-weight:bold;
}
```

i want the last `span` with "red" content to be red. how i can do it with css ?

**update:**
there is a solution with `last-of-type` for elements with same parents. but what about different parents ?

Comment: have you tried [`last-of-type`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:last-of-type), note this is a css3 selector and not available in IE below 9

Comment: @PatrickEvans how i can try this? like `*:last-of-type span:last-child` ?

Comment: yea its a pseudo class like `last-child`, `span:last-of-type`

Comment: @PatrickEvans: can you make a fiddle i tried by did not work

Comment: never mind looks like it acts like `last-child`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try this: (*you should be aware of the parent wrapper element*)

```
body > *:last-child > span:last-child{
    color: red;
}
```

[**Working Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/venkateshwar/bF3FC/2/)

Comment: This only works if it is inside of the very last element of the page. In other words, the document structure has to be known